# javascript timezone format

Tags: javascript, timezone

I need to format a javascript Date to send via json to the server.  The server expects the time to be in the format according to this example

`2011-08-31T06:49:28.931 -0700`

which it conveniently tells me when I try to submit something like

`2011-08-31T06:49:28.931 -07:00`

The trouble I am having is with the timezone part, `-0700`.  I've been looking at the Date API, and don't see a way to specify the timezone format.  I can do `d.getTimezoneOffset`, but it returns 240 (Im in EDT I think) for me.

So, I can convert 240 to 0400 to represent 4 hours.  I am worried however about correctness for other timezones.  My questions are

1)  How to convert the result of the `getTimezoneOffset()` into the required format, and how to determine what the sign should be (thats the part I am worried about)?

2)  Is there a way to get the format off the date object itself so I don't have to do anything custom?  If i do `d.toString()` I get `"Wed Aug 31 2011 09:48:27 GMT-0400 (EDT)"`, so here the timezone part is in the format I want.  So it might be possible.   Maybe the best solution is to just use a regex to grab the timezone off `d.toString()`...

3)  Extra credit: is the format the server requires some sort of standard?

Update: using `match(/^.*GMT(-?\d*)/)` returns "-0400" at index 1 of the array.  Perhaps I should just use that?  Im wondering if that regex will work for all timezones in the context of the sign.

Comment: You have already tested the method toJSON() ?

Comment: @andrew what do you mean? `toJson` returns something like "2011-08-31T14:29:38.924Z" which doesn't seem to include any timezone info

Comment: (new Date(Date.now())).toJSON() outputs date as string "2011-08-31T14:31:48.875Z" in Greenwich Time zone.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
var d=new Date(Date.now()); // sets your date to variable d

function repeat(str,count) { // EXTENSION
  return new Array(count+1).join(str);
};

function padLeft(str,length,char) { // EXTENSION
  return length<=str.length ? str.substr(0,length) : repeat(String(char||" ").substr(0,1),length-str.length)+str;
};

var str=padLeft(String(d.getFullYear()),4,"0")+"-"+
        padLeft(String(d.getMonth()),2,"0")+"-"+
        padLeft(String(d.getDate()),2,"0")+"T"+
        padLeft(String(d.getHours()),2,"0")+":"+
        padLeft(String(d.getMinutes()),2,"0")+":"+
        padLeft(String(d.getSeconds()),2,"0")+"."+
        d.getMilliseconds();
//str+=" GMT";
var o=d.getTimezoneOffset(),s=o<0?"+":"-",h,m;
h=Math.floor(Math.abs(o)/60);
m=Math.abs(o)-h*60;

str+=" "+s+padLeft(String(h),2,"0")+padLeft(String(m),2,"0");

alert(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use one of the date/time formatting libraries that bakes in support for this timezone format (such as http://jacwright.com/projects/javascript/date_format/). In any case, you're right: there really is no good way to control the format output.

As far as the regex goes I don't know that all browsers consistently use the GMT string format, so that may not be the best path forward.